# My JQuery validation plugin behaves strangely with checkbox inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, plugins, jquery-plugins

I wrote my own general use validation plugin(s) which take a function to check if the input is valid and then a callback for each of the cases where the input is determined to be valid and invalid by the first function.

Basically, the plugin consists of two functions, '$.fn.validation()' to bind an object containing validation logic and success/failure callbacks to a element and then '$.fn.validate()' to either invoke the validation object, or if a new object is passed in it will use the new object for this one instance. Implementation of the plugins and [a jsfiddle demonstrating the issues](https://jsfiddle.net/hc0qc50r/4/) described below can be found here.

My issue is that while text input and texareas seem to work really well in all cases, depending on how some elements, such as checkbox inputs, are selected, elements may not get validated despite being in the set of elements returned by the jQuery element

For example, the following selector will not result in check boxes being validated

```
$('input, textarea').validate();
```

However a more specific selector will result in the checkboxes being validated

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').validate();
```

Again, [please checkout the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc0qc50r/4/) where I have replicated the issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When I run the fiddle, and click "Submit Form" without checking the checkbox, it turns red.

Comment: oh sorry, $('input[type=checkbox]').validate(); at line 89 should have been commented out. I must have forgotten to save it before i shared the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're extracting the validation options *outside* the `this.each()` loop in the `.validate()` code:

```
  $.fn.validate = function(options){

    var validation = $.extend({
      check: $(this).data("check") || function(input){ return true },
      success: $(this).data("success") || function (input){},
      failure: $(this).data("failure") || function (input){}
    }, options);

    var valid = true;

    this.each(function(){
      if(validation.check($(this))){
        validation.success($(this));
      } else {
        validation.failure($(this));
        valid = false;
      }
    });

    return valid;
  };
```

When you set up `validation`, you're grabbing the validation configuration for the first element in the selected list, and that will be what's used for all the elements.

Instead, that code should be inside the `this.each()` callback:

```
$.fn.validate = function (options) {


    var valid = true;

    this.each(function () {
        var validation = $.extend({
            check: $(this).data("check") || function (input) {
                return true
            },
            success: $(this).data("success") || function (input) {},
            failure: $(this).data("failure") || function (input) {}
        }, options);
        if (validation.check($(this))) {
            validation.success($(this));
        } else {
            validation.failure($(this));
            valid = false;
        }
    });

    return valid;
};
```

It worked when you did the `input[type=checkbox]` separately because then the validation configuration would be the one for the checkbox (the only element selected by that selector).

Comment: 10/10 Good sir. Kind of embarrassed that I didn't pick up on that myself. and Thanks heaps for your prompt response.

Comment: @user2422529 it was an interesting bug :)